# Jenkins - Maven - Deploy zip to network disk location and unzip

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a Maven project with static resources whose deployment we want to automate.

The project pom.xml is configured with **maven-assembly-plugin** so that it generates a zip file with a subset of the resources. Whenever there is a build in Jenkins we want to take that zip, deploy it to a remote folder and unzip it.

How could we achive it with Maven + Jenkins?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `mvn deploy`. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/

Comment: @Tunaki maven-deploy-plugin allows us to copy the zip file but what we're not sure about is the unzipping. Is there a Maven/Jenkins way to automate that part?

Comment: Jenkins can connect through SSH to a remote server and execute the commands you want: take a look at SSH Plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin

Comment: @Tunaki that is likely to work. We're gonna give it a try. Thanks!